# Redirection 301 .HTACCESS with exception

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I would divide my personal blog `(https:__mypersonalwebsite_com`) made in Wordpress into two website:

1) `https__mypersonalwebsite_com` with the homepage and other few specific pages (for ex: `https:__mypersonalwebsite.com/contatti`)

2) `https:__mysecondwebsite.com` with all the rest of the content/pages redirected from `https:__mypersonalwebsite.com`

For do that, I have copied the `https:_mypersonalwebsite.com` into the second website `https://mysecondwebsite.com` (now I have two perfect website running)
Then what I've done is modify the .htaccess wit the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/contatti/
RewriteRule ^.*$ https:_mysecondwebsite/$0 [R=301,L]
```

But doesn't work. I go to `https:_mypersonalwebsite.com/contatti/` i go directly to the `https:_mysecondwebsite.com` homepage.
what is wrong?

And then, what is the code to NOT redirect the homepage from `https:_mypersonalwebsite.com` to

```
https:_mypersonalwebsite.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this rule at top of your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(?:www\.)?mysecondwebsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+contatti/ [NC]
RewriteRule . https://mysecondwebsite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

And clear your browser cache before testing.
```

Comment: Thank you!It seems it work. But there is a problem: if I go to https__mypersonalwebsite_com it redirect to https:_mysecondwebsite.com (homepage) and I don't want that because I Want to develop two different Website...

Comment: Sorry Anubhava, maybe I was'n clear when I explained mi issue. What I what is to redirect ALL the content from httpS://mypersonalwebsite.com to httpS://mysecondwebsite.com APART the following pages: 1) httpS://mypersonalwebsite.com HOME PAGE 2)httpS://mypersonalwebsite.com/contatti/ 3) ... Let me know if its clear now. I want to do this because I want to insert content in the two different website separetely. Let me know i I am clear. Thank you :)

Comment: Keep this rule as your very first rule in .htaccess. If you notice I have `RewriteRule .` where `.` in pattern will not matching home/landing page. Also make sure to clear your browser cache.

Comment: Yes...still not working...can I send you the links of the two Websites on linkedin? Or is against StackOverflow Policy? Marco